# (Noch) eine Frage über die Reihenfolge von Satzgliedern

Tags: sentence-structure

Bei einer Übung* hatte ich den folgenden Satz geschrieben

> Wenn die Gesprächspartner sich auch so bemühten, konnten nicht alle Meinungsverschiedenheiten ausgeräumt werden.

während die Lösung hieß

> Wenn sich die Gesprächspartner auch noch so bemühten, nicht alle Meinungsverschiedenheiten konnten ausgeräumt werden

- zu meinen Ohren klang es "richtig", dass ich das Verb "konnten" direkt nach dem Nebensatz stellte.  Warum ist das falsch?
- muss *sich* vor dem Nomen gehen?

Ähnlich hier, wobei ich Folgendes geschrieben habe

> Auch wenn es sehr offen diskutiert wird, kann es Missverständnisse geben

obwohl die Lösung Folgendes ist

> Auch wenn sehr offen diskutiert wird, Missverständnisse kann es geben

- noch einmal scheine ich den selben Fehler zu begehen, indem ich das Verb direkt nach dem Nebensatz stelle.  Warum ist das nicht korrekt?
- braucht man das "es" wegzulassen?

---

*von Hueber "Übungsgrammatik für die Oberstufe Aktuell"

Comment: Deine Antworten sind korrekt. Die "Lösungen" sind zweifelhaft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die "Lösung" hängt einen Hauptsatz, ohne die Satzstruktur anzupassen, an den Nebensatz an. Das Verb gehört an die zweite Position (bei Aussagen), und der Nebensatz nimmt schon die erste Position ein. Die Satzstruktur wäre korrekt, wenn statt dessen der Hauptsatz vorne stehen würde. Korrekt wäre:

> Missverständnisse kann es geben, auch wenn sehr offen diskutiert wird.

oder Deine Version

> Auch wenn es sehr offen diskutiert wird, kann es Missverständnisse geben.

Beim ersten Beispiel hat die "Lösung" das gleiche Problem.

Statt Deinem Beispiel würde ich schreiben "Wenn sie sich (auch) noch so (sehr) bemühten". Ohne "noch" ist der Satz zwar verständlich, kling aber seltsam. Ich würde eher das "auch" weglassen als das "noch".

Außerdem passt bei "wenn" das Bemühen nicht mit dem fehlenden Erfolg zusammen:

> Obwohl die Gesprächspartner sich (auch) noch so bemühten, konnten nicht alle Meinungsverschiedenheiten ausgeräumt werden.

Erfolg:

> Wenn/Weil die Gesprächspartner sich bemühten, konnten alle Meinungsverschiedenheiten ausgeräumt werden.